Spring Gateway Disable Oauth2 Login Page
I am using Spring Cloud Gateway and Spring Auth Server for a project. The gateway is the oauth2 client. Everything works fine, any unauthenticated request redirects to auth server, get the session, token etc. However, there is a "login" page in the gateway project, which I can neither remove nor disable. In some cases, logout process redirects to there, and in that page, my Oauth2 clients are listed.
I've tried creating a controller to override the /login endpoint, did not succeed. I've tried redirecting from the gateway config, did not succeed. I tried to replace the html for that page, did not succeed. The worst part is, I can not find any resources about this login page. The only resource is https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/login/advanced.html#webflux-oauth2-login-advanced-login-page, and it does not tell anything about disabling.
I need to remove/disable this page. No override, no customization. I already have a login page in the auth server, and the /login endpoint should redirect to that page as any other unauthenticated request. How can I do it?
Used versions: Spring boot starter 3.3.2, spring cloud starter gateway 4.1.5.


I've tried creating a controller to override the /login endpoint

It would be worth sharing the source of this controller, as well as the DEBUG logs you get.
In the doc you link, there an ! IMPORTANT note:

You need to provide a @Controller with a @RequestMapping

So have you tried to do as instructed?

set exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login/auto-redirect"))
define a @Controller with a @RequestMapping("/login/auto-redirect") returning a new RedirecView("/oauth2/authorization/id-of-a-registration-with-authorization-code")

Also, you'll need to permitAll() this controller endpoint.
Side note
Your OAuth2 client being a gateway makes me think it is an OAuth2 BFF between a REST API and a single-page or mobile application. If that's the case, returning 401 to Unauthorized requests would be much more RESTful than 302 Found. How unauthorized requests are handled should be the responsibility of the frontend.

Thanks, I found my problem. Too long for comment, I'll add it as a response.

The controller code was similar to the one @ch4mp shared.
@Controller
class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    RedirectView redirect() {
        return new RedirectView("/oauth2/authorization/{authcode}");
    }
}

The difference is, I needed to override the /login endpoint, so did not use /login/auto-redirect as @ch4mp suggested.
The problem is, in the security config, I needed to add the /login endpoint to the  "permitAll()" group. Without that, it stucks in a redirect loop.
.pathMatchers(
              "/static/**",
              "/login"
             ).permitAll()

Apparently, there is no "disable" switch for the login page. It can only be overridden. That sucks.
For the side note, yes it is an OAuth2 BFF, and when I added the Unauthorized response like this
exceptionHandling(exceptionHandlingSpec ->
                        exceptionHandlingSpec.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))

it does not redirect to the auth server. All of the legitimate requests are returned as Unauthorized. This does not work, or I could not make it so.

Of course à 401 does not instruct a browser to redirect. But a single page or mobile application should handle a 401 (not only, it should handle all error codes). In Angular you have HTTP i'terceptors for that.

The problem is, it should do a redirect before the angular ui is loaded. If there is no session when the angular ui is called, it should redirect to login. Angular ui is behind the session control, for some reason. I understand the logic behind it, but scenario does not fit. Thanks again.

"Angular ui is behind the session control, for some reason." Angular ui is behind the session control, because you configured the Gateway like that. You can perfectly serve Angular assets with a stateless filter-chain and permitAll(). Just as you can, like I wrote already, return 401 for Unauthorized REST requests to protected resources and intercept these 401 responses with an interceptor in Angular.

You can customize exception handling as suggested by @ch4mp to handle this. You can actually skip defining your own controller endpoint if you know which ClientRegistration you would like to use for the redirect, and directly provide a relative URL as in new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/oauth2/authorization/google"). However, customizing http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint() directly has the downside of losing default content-negotation of requests for non text/html media types.
"Add loginPage() to DSL in reactive oauth2Login() #15674" was recently resolved to specifically address this scenario. It will be available in Spring Security 6.4.0 current scheduled for release in November 2024.
